# Is it possible to match multiple specific line numbers (not range) with sed?

Tags: sed, patterns

Consider:

```
echo -e "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng\nh" | sed '3,5a test'
```

This will match lines 3, 4 and 5.

But I am trying to match only lines 3 and 5 (not 4). And append 'test' after them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
echo ... | sed -e '3a test' -e '5a test'
```

If the operation is more complex than in this case then you can use a structure like this:

```
sed 'b pattern; : action; a \
lalala
b end; : pattern; 3b action; 5b action; : end'
```

I.e. you put all commands you need between `b pattern;` and `b end;`.

And you add all your patterns (line numbers or whatever) after `: pattern;`.

What happens is this:

1. The first command jumps over the action part (maybe it's easier to read if the patterns are at the beginning and `b end;` directly before the action part).
2. If a pattern matches then the execution jumps to the action part. After the action part execution jumps to the end.

I try to tidy this up:

```
sed '3b action; 5b action; b end; : action; a \
lalala
: end'
```

In a single line would be like:

```
sed "3b idAction; 5b idAction; b; : idAction; a test"
```

Portably, you need to write it:

```
sed '
   3b action
   5b action
   b
   : action
   a\
   lalala'
```

(`b` without label branches to the end, so you don't need an explicit `end` label, `;` is valid a character in a label in standard `sed` implementations).

Comment: Wow, sed subroutines. Cool

Comment: Wow indeed, could you expand on those? They look really useful!

Comment: the one with 'pattern' and 'action' seems very good as I do not need to repeat 'test' (or 'lalala'), got to still better understand it tho thx! :)

Comment: @terdon What could I?

Comment: I meant that the second one looks great but is hard to understand and if you have the time, I'd appreciate an explanation.

Comment: Thanks! I'd upvote you but I had already done so on the 1st version.

Comment: cool! btw, can it be a single line? or is a sed limitation?

Comment: @AquariusPower It didn't work for me in a single line. This problem is specific to `a`. With an `s` command instead it is no problem.

Comment: @HaukeLaging with the last tip, I managed to single line it up: `echo -e "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng\nh" |sed "3b idAction; 5b idAction; b; : idAction; a test"` thx!

Answer (score 5):

With `sed` (see @HaukeLaging's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117513/22222))

With `awk`:

```
$ echo -e "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng\nh" | awk 'NR==3 || NR==5{$0=$0"\ntest"}1;'
```

With `perl`:

```
$ echo -e "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng\nh" | perl -pe '$_ .="test\n" if $. == 3 || $. == 5'
```

Comment: Can golf your perl a bit, using the "smart match" operator: `perl -lnE 'say if $. ~~ @{[3,5]}'`

Comment: @glennjackman ah, yes indeed, thanks. I have to admit that I'm a bit wary of `~~`, don't understand it as well as I should. Also, both `say` and `~~` need perl v >= 5.10 right?

Comment: I need to append 'test' after that lines, I see now it would have been better to have clarified that from the beginning. I just edited the OP.

Comment: @AquariusPower, `perl -pE 'say "test" if $. ~~ @{[4,6]}'` -- this *prepends* the line: perl's `-p` does an implicit print at the *end* of the given program.

Comment: @AquariusPower also see updated answer.

Comment: @glennjackman it doesn't always though, at least it seems to ignore `next`. I've never been able to figure out quite how it works. For example, try `echo -e "a\nb\nc" | perl -pe 'next if /b/'`. That will still print the second line despite the `next`.

Comment: That's because the print is in a "continue" block: `while (<>) { your code ...} continue {print}`, and only "redo" and "last" skip the continue block. See "[perldoc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)" and "[perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html)".

Comment: @glennjackman yes, I was actually just typing a question on this so I re-read `man perlrun` and saw that I had missed that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

As @HaukeLaging aleady said, this command does what you want:

```
sed -e'3a test' -e'5a test'
```

Now, this can become rather cumbersome to type if you want to match, e.g., 20 lines.

In these cases, assuming your shell supports [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html), you can use this command instead:

```
sed -e{3,5}'a test'
```

(Note that the braces and the comma must remain unquoted.)

As a result, the shell will pass the arguments to `-e3a test` and `-e5a test` to sed, which is exactly what the first command does.